# fonts from (previously) installed version of MikTex

Tags: fonts, miktex, installing

I have to install Miktex on x64, Windows machines. And make sure there are the same completes of fonts as on Miktex 2.9, windows machine x32, installed some years ago. (there is no problem with fonts in separate folders, but) some, no longer available fonts (Korean etc) are in the main MikTex folder of the x32 machine. Can I just copy MikTex 2.9/dvipdfm, Miktex 2.9/dvips, Miktex 2.9/fonts folders from the x32 machine, initexmf/update the new installation on x64? Thank you for help.

Comment: well you can copy stuff. But I wouldn't copy things in the main folder of miktex but in some local texmf. And I wouldn't copy everything but check what is needed what not.